# Nav bar background color not showing in Xcode

Tags: swift, xcode, storyboard, navbar

I have the following code:

```
      override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: .default)
    navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
}
```

and what this does is just remove the background color from the nav bar although it doesn't work right away.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1MJLyTMEwr6CIeIl_ljAGR-uNBdUo-iBk/view?usp=sharing

Above is a google drive video of what is happening, its really hard to explain but I'll do my best. I have 3 steps in my app to set up and account, when I run the simulator for first step, the nav bar is white. I press the next button Then the second step the nav bar is white. When I go to the 3rd step though the nav bar is transparent which is what I want. Furthermore, when I then go back to steps 1 and 2 the nav bar is transparent. 
I have tried reseting my simulator but I really have no idea what I am doing wrong. Someone please help

Comment: What is it that you _want_ to do?

Comment: I couldn't replicate your problem, I used the same lines of code and it worked on mine. Try moving those lines to viewDidLayoutSubviews() instead of viewDidLoad().

Comment: @paulRick I just tried that but it was the same result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a new `UIViewController` for each view in your Storyboard and wire it by Choosing the class in the Inspector on the right hand side of the storyboard... Your current code is only applied to the `UIViewControllers` that you told the Storyboard Editor to be of type `ViewController`. Split up your content to multiple classes and you can specify for each VC how the nav bar should look like.

Hope that helps, feel free to ask further questions.

Comment: I am new to app development so I am a little bit confused by what you just said, would you be able to be a bit more clear in the steps.

Comment: Nevermind, I just had to change the class from UIViewController To ViewController

Comment: I'm not sure if I got it right from your video but it looked like you have 4-5 views defined in the storyboard but only one class of a `UIViewController`, called `ViewController.swift`. What I was trying to say is that you should create a `.swift` Version of each view in the Storyboard and link them, and then you'd have to insert the code for the clear navigation bar in every `.swift` file to the respective view controller... But I'm glad it might have given you an idea and you were able to fix in eventually. Have fun with app development!